Powerquery, convert list to row-wise values
I have the following code, with the following JSON structure: (the elements are lists)

let
    Source = Json.Document("[{""var"":[""var1"", ""var2""], ""visitor"":[""vis1"", ""vis2""]}]"),
    myTab = Table.FromRecords(Source)
in
    myTab

but I would get would be an output like this:
(the elements of the columns would be lists instead of the displayed values):
https://imgur.com/a/HgBA4Tw
However, what I would need, would be an expansion of all the lists in the columns,
as if you would be typing this:
let
    Source = Json.Document("[{""var"":""var1"", ""visitor"":""vis1""},{""var"":""var2"", ""visitor"":""vis2""}]"),
    myTab = Table.FromRecords(Source)
in
    myTab

so my question is there some power query prompt such that
Json.Document("[{""var"":[""var1"", ""var2""], ""visitor"":[""vis1"", ""vis2""]}]") 

can be automatically and dynamically be transformed to
Json.Document("[{""var"":""var1"", ""visitor"":""vis1""},{""var"":""var2"", ""visitor"":""vis2""}]") 

without changing the JSON beforehand manually? Such that the transformation is done via PowerQuery itself. By dynamic I mean that I wouldn't have to type any column name, or the number of columns, because I have huge JSON files with always the exact same structure but changing column number/names (there are lists inside the columns which all would have to be converted rowwise)
The number of list elements for all columns are always equal.
What I tried was to manually change the JSON file, but that wouldn't be feasible for my actual use-case.
example with more data (both the number of the list elements inside, as well as the head columns (var, visitor, customer, ....) would increase, however if that makes any difference: the number of the items in the list would always be equal for all columns, for example if var=[var1,var2,....,var10], then also visitor=[vis1, vis2, ... , vis10]
so both would be having 10 elements, and so on

let
    Source = Json.Document("[{""var"":[""var1"", ""var2"", ""var3"", ""var4""], ""visitor"":[""vis1"", ""vis2"", ""vis3"", ""vis4""], ""customer"":[""cus1"", ""cus2"", ""cus3"", ""cus4""]}]"),
    myTab = Table.FromRecords(Source)
in
    myTab


Why not just expand the Source into columns.
With your data, you could use the following:
let
    Source = Json.Document("[{""var"":[""var1"", ""var2""], ""visitor"":[""vis1"", ""vis2""]}]"),
    #"Column Names" = Record.FieldNames(Source{0}),
    #"Column Values" = Record.FieldValues(Source{0}),
    myTab = Table.FromColumns(#"Column Values",#"Column Names")
in
    myTab


Or, substituting your last Source for the source line in the above:
let
    Source = Json.Document("[{""var"":[""var1"", ""var2"", ""var3"", ""var4""], ""visitor"":[""vis1"", ""vis2"", ""vis3"", ""vis4""], ""customer"":[""cus1"", ""cus2"", ""cus3"", ""cus4""]}]"),

    #"Column Names" = Record.FieldNames(Source{0}),
    #"Column Values" = Record.FieldValues(Source{0}),
    myTab = Table.FromColumns(#"Column Values",#"Column Names")
in
    myTab


